# Python ModuleNotFound After Successful Install from Local pypi-server

Tags: python, pycharm, pypi, modulenotfounderror, pypiserver

Python 3.8

Package Project

```
-my_package
  |
  |-dist
  |-test_framework
     |
     |-test_folder
          |-__init__.py
     |-cycle_folder
          |-__init__.py
  |-venv
  |.pypirc
  |__init__.py
  |LICENSE.txt
  |README.md
  |setup.cfg
```

Created package with `pip install -e`.

Running `pypi-server run -p 9000 .` from the `venv` in this project.

In my client project, ran
`pip3 install --extra-index-url http://localhost:9000 my_package`, and it successfully installed the package.

`pip show my_package` shows the whole

```
Name: ...
Version:...
Location: c:\git\my_project\venv\lib\site-packages
```

In my "client" code,

```
import my_package
```

results in ModuleNotFound.

+However+ - the *test_framework* module *is* installed as a package!

#### Setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="my_package",
    version="0.1.0",
    description="whatever",
    author="ABC",
    author_email="xxx@xxxx.com",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        # Add your package dependencies here
    ],
)
```

Using
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel